# SQL query to find duplicate records and discount from COUNT with condition AND

Tags: sql, join, group-by, count

I am using below SQL query to count the records. I would like to discount the duplicate testID after I got the count.

example:

```
select count (*) from PRODUCT MP
   join PRODUCT_UOM pu on pu.PRODUCT_KEY = mp.PRODUCT_KEY
   join UOM u on u.UOM_ID = pu.UOM_ID
   join PRODUCT_BARCODE pb on pb.PRODUCT_UOM_KEY = pu.PRODUCT_UOM_KEY
```

the excel data when query select * looks like below:

[image]

i want to discount the records which TESTID AND NAME is duplicate.

total count = 6 - 2 = 4

I understand there is **distinct** query which i can used, but i am not sure how to make condition with 2 columns, when duplicate then do not count them.

Comment: Can you show your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some databases (namely, MySQL) support list of columns in `count(distinct)`, so you can just do:

```
select count(testid, name) cnt
from product mp
join product_uom pu on pu.product_key = mp.product_key
join uom u on u.uom_id = pu.uom_id
join product_barcode pb on pb.product_uom_key = pu.product_uom_key
```

Note that you should qualify the column names with the table they belong to, to make the query clearer and avoid ambiguity.
Another option is to concatenate the columns and use `count(distinct)`. You need to chose a separator the does not appear in of the strings being concatenated to avoid "fake" duplicates:

```
select count(distinct concat(testid, '###', name)) cnt
from product mp
join product_uom pu on pu.product_key = mp.product_key
join uom u on u.uom_id = pu.uom_id
join product_barcode pb on pb.product_uom_key = pu.product_uom_key
```

You can also use `distinct`  in a subquery, and then `count()`:

```
select count(*) cnt
from (
    select distinct testid, name 
    from product mp
    join product_uom pu on pu.product_key = mp.product_key
    join uom u on u.uom_id = pu.uom_id
    join product_barcode pb on pb.product_uom_key = pu.product_uom_key
) t
```

Comment: SQL Error [102] [S0001]: Incorrect syntax near 'cnt'.

Comment: @user12158726: there are three queries in the answer, which one are you using (note that I modified them)?

Comment: select count(distinct concat(testid, '###', name) cnt
from product mp
join product_uom pu on pu.product_key = mp.product_key
join uom u on u.uom_id = pu.uom_id
join product_barcode pb on pb.product_uom_key = pu.product_uom_key

Comment: @user12158726: there is a missing closing parenthese before `count()`. Please run the query as given in my answer (I fixed that in between).

Comment: select count(distinct concat(DRUG_CODE, '###', SHORT_NAME)) cnt
from product mp
join product_uom pu on pu.product_key = mp.product_key
join uom u on u.uom_id = pu.uom_id
join product_barcode pb on pb.product_uom_key = pu.product_uom_key

Answer (score 1):

You can reuse your existing query. For example:

```
select count(*) from (
  select distinct testid, name 
  from PRODUCT MP
  join PRODUCT_UNIT pu on pu.PRODUCT_KEY = mp.PRODUCT_KEY
  join UNITu on u.UNIT_ID = pu.UNIT_ID
  join PRODUCT_BAR pb on pb.PRODUCT_UNIT_KEY = pu.PRODUCT_UNIT_KEY
) x
```

Your existing query acts as a table expresison, but you replace `COUNT(*)` by `DISTINCT TESTID, NAME`.

Comment: SQL Error [156] [S0001]: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.

Comment: select count (*) from 
       select distinct DRUG_CODE, SHORT_NAME
       from PRODUCT MP
       join PRODUCT_UOM pu on pu.PRODUCT_KEY = mp.PRODUCT_KEY
       join UOM u on u.UOM_ID = pu.UOM_ID
       join PRODUCT_BARCODE pb on pb.PRODUCT_UOM_KEY = pu.PRODUCT_UOM_KEY

Comment: @user12158726 you missed the `()` around the subquery (and the table alias)

Answer (score 0):

If it is just the `count` that is important to you could simply use `GROUP BY` on `TESTID, NAME` and then count the number of rows in that query like so :

```
SELECT count(t.*) from (

   select * from PRODUCT MP
   join PRODUCT_UNIT pu on pu.PRODUCT_KEY = mp.PRODUCT_KEY
   join UNIT u on u.UNIT_ID = pu.UNIT_ID
   join PRODUCT_BAR pb on pb.PRODUCT_UNIT_KEY = pu.PRODUCT_UNIT_KEY

   GROUP BY TESTID, NAME
) t;
```

Comment: SQL Error [102] [S0001]: Incorrect syntax near '*'.